# Python importing module goes wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

If I import a module in a python (2.7.13) script e.g

```
from winappdbg import breakpoint
```

and execute it with the IDLE Python Shell,
I get an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name breakpoint
```

If I run from the commandline:

```
>> python
>> from winappdbg import breakpoint
```

everything is fine.

Same problem if I run the script via Commandline:

```
>> python C:\path\to\script.py
```

results in the same error

- The Python Version displayed by the IDLE Shell is exactly the same like the one displayed by the Commandline Command.
- I checked the PYTHONPATH and also tried to add the script manually to the PYTHONPATH with no effect.
- I also tried different Python Versions - still the same problem.

I do not know how to continue - so maybe someone have an idea or got the same problem?

Comment: show the whole traceback please, can you do just `import winappdbg`?

Comment: Where are you running it from?  Did you happen to create your own file called `winappdb.py` somewhere?

Comment: @BrenBarn ouh man you got me here. For testing purpose i used the name "winappdbg.py" as script name. I did not think about that - but yeah its clear that this cant work - thank you